# Delete a table row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this to add a row:

```
function myFunction4() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1); 
  var produs = $( "#produs4" ).val(); 
  var cantitate = $(".cantitate4").val(); 
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = produs;
  cell2.innerHTML = cantitate; 
  cell3.innerHTML = " <input type='button' value='X' onclick='SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)'>"
  $(".overlay_cantitate4").fadeOut(500)
}
```

Then I tried this to delete it but it doesn't work

```
function SomeDeleteRowFunction() {
  var p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
  p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}
```

variables

```
<select id="produs4"><option selected="selected"> Prajitura cu mar </option></select> 
             <center> <input class="cantitate4 cantitate" type="text" value="1">
```

Comment: Could you complete your code and show what's the value of the o variable.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. This as it stands is missing vital information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your delete function put this code in while  you delete

```
    function SomeDeleteRowFunction(element) {
      var p = element.parentNode.parentNode;
      p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    }
```

Comment: So the question is : why are you using jQuery then @Alessandro?

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery, look upwards for a `row` tag, and remove it.

```
<script>
function SomeDeleteRowFunction() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: does not worrk eighter

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery it's better to attach the click event in your JS code,

First give the target a class like :

```
cell3.innerHTML = " <input type='button' value='X' class='some_class'>"
```

Then attach the click event :

```
$('body').on('click', '.some_class', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**NOTE :** We should use the event delegation **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** here since the elements are dynamically generated.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.closest`, which is available in plain javascript too:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest.

Note that this is not supported in IE and Edge, but there is a polyfill available.

---

Also in jQuery would be better to use `.closest()` method, because it finds just one closest element and not all matching elements among node parents:

From: https://api.jquery.com/parents/

> matching elements ordered from immediate parent on up; the elements are returned in order from the closest parent to the outer ones.